# How to choose a folder if Open function is used in VC6 ?

Tags: c++, visual-c++-6

I have the following code which save the .csv file on the Desktop. I want to change the code so users can choose where to save it and name it as well.

```
std::ofstream outfile;
outfile.open("Real-Time.csv", std::ios_base::app);
outfile<<TotalTime<<", "<<os.str().c_str()<<", "<<os1.str().c_str()<<endl;
```

Comment: Console app? Win32 GUI App? MFC App? You're a bit light on the details.

Comment: Sorry, it is a  Win32 GUI App

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using VC6, which is to put it mildly, ancient technology, the solution you probably need is the old [GetSaveFileNameW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/commdlg/nf-commdlg-getsavefilenamew) function.  There's a narrow character version as well if you need such a thing.

Note that since Vista, that's been replaced by the [Common Item Dialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb776913(v=VS.85).aspx), if you go that route, you'd be looking at IFileSaveDialog.